# Anaconda: UnsatisfiableError while installing mgwr

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install [mgwr](https://mgwr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on my mac where I have installed both `python 2.7.x` and `python 3.7.x`

```
conda install -c conda-forge mgwr
```

During the installation I get the following error

Solving environment: failed

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - mgwr
  - scandir
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```